# work with checkbox.?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want usually when the user manually checks all the checkboxes, the checkall checkbox should become checked, and when user unchecks one box so that "all" aren't checked, the checkall box should become unchecked. how is it in my code?

**EXAMPLE:** [here is full my code](http://jsfiddle.net/cQYVE/5/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go

http://jsfiddle.net/cQYVE/13/

Just add the below code in the `tr` click handler in your code.

```
$('.table_show tr input:first').prop('checked', 
     shouldCheck && ($('.table_show tr:gt(0) input:not(:checked)').length == 0));
```

Answer (score 2):

Just check how many boxes are checked:

```
var $master = $('th input'),
    $slaves = $('td input');

$slaves.change(function() {
    var state = true;

    $slaves.each(function(){
        if ( this.checked == false ) {
            state = false;
            return false;
        }
    });

    $master.prop('checked', state);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cQYVE/16/

Comment: Hang on...this fails when all are checked (including master) and you deselect one of the 'options'.

Comment: @josh.trow: Isn't that what you wanted? You want the master checkbox to only be checked if all others are checked. Or did I get that wrong?

Comment: Better if you get the number of checkboxes dynamically (and store it somewhere). Also, whenever you unselect a checkbox, you can deselect the *all* checkbox, no need to count the selected ones.

Comment: @Felix Kling: ...and many more optimizations (such as caching the selectors). Was merely trying to point him in the right direction.

Comment: @Joseph Silber: No, you have the idea correct, but somehow I occasionally get the first option to deselect but have the master still selected.

Comment: @josh.trow: Or vice versa, but I think this is a problem of the whole setup and not this part of the code.

Comment: @josh.trow: it seems to have been a bug in jQuery's `:checked`. I changed the code completely, let me know if it works for you now.

Comment: @Joseph Silber: I can still get it to fail - maybe I'm changing it too fast for the code to handle? I would say I'm clicking at about a rate of 2-3 clicks/second...

Comment: @josh.trow: Maybe there's something wrong with me, but I've been doing this clickity clack for 2 minutes straight, and could not get it to fail.

Comment: @Joseph Silber: I figured it out - he is listening for clicks on the ROWS - not just checkboxes. Try clicking the master to select them all, then click an option ROW, not checkbox. That should make it fail.

Comment: @josh.trow: +1 for your detective work ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/cQYVE/18/

(Small improvements on ShankarSangoli's solution)

Comment: Select them all (including master) then deselect any of the options. The master stays selected.

Comment: Yep, I just fixed that as you were commenting on it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!$('input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)').length)
    do('stuff');
```

This will check if there are any that are unchecked, and do stuff if there aren't (i.e. they are all checked)